# How to write unit test for mvc. In class a method return a list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to write unit test for below code. Easy understanding of the solution. I novice for unit testing. I don't know how write. I have added unit test class successfully from solution explorer.

class 1:

```
public class ListModel
{
public int EmpID { get; set; }
public string EmpName {get;set;}
public string CusID {get; set;}
public string EmpType { get; set; }
public string EmpPDLC { get; set; }
public int? EmpMode { get; set; }
public int? Status { get; set; }
}
```

class 2:

```
public class EmployeeHelper : IEmployeeHelper 
{
public List<ListModel> EmployeeList(int userId)
        {
            var lstModel = new List<ListModel>();
            try
            {
                using (var dc = new EmployeeDataContext())
                {
                    var lstGetTable = (from table in dc.UserTables
                                                                    where table.UserID == userId && table.Status == 1 
                                                                    select table).ToList();

                    lstModel.AddRange(lstGetTable.Select(items => new ListModel
                    {
                        EmpID = items.EmpID,
                            EmpName = items.EmpName, 
            CustID = items.CustID,
                            EmpType = items.EmpType, 
            EmpPDLC = items.EmpPDLC,                                 
                            EmpMode = items.EmpMode, 
                            Status = items.Status
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return lstModel;
            }
            return lstModel;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is more readable

Comment: There are several questions and answers regarding unit testing in StackOverflow. Start looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1934448/1016343). It tells you how to create a test for a class in VS. Once you are familiar with it, continue looking in the Q & A to find more specific topics.

Comment: @Matt- There is no solution in the Link. In my question method that return List<class> values. How to write if method return List??

Comment: @Param. In its current state your question is **too broad**. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.